# How to apply kmeans clustering on gray scale image in matlab

Tags: matlab, k-means, image-segmentation

[skin cancer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYp7r.jpg)
I want to apply K means clustering on grayscale image, code is as follow

```
    im = imread('SSM1_2_orig.jpg');
im = rgb2gray(im);
[idx centroids]=kmeans(double(im(:)),3,'distance','sqEuclidean','Replicates',3);
%imseg = zeros(size(im,1),size(im,2));
%{for i=1:max(idx)
    %imseg(idx==i)=i;
    %end}
segmented_images = cell(1,3);
for k = 1:3
    color = im;
    color(im ~= k) = 0;
    segmented_images{k} = color;
end

figure(),imshow(segmented_images{1});
figure(),imshow(segmented_images{2});
figure(),imshow(segmented_images{3});
```

but it gives me the black output only

Comment: have you tried `imshow(segmented_images{1},[]);`

Comment: yes ,but it gives the black output only

Comment: Then can you please add the original image so we can try it?

Comment: yes, It related to skin cancer

Comment: `idx` and `centroids` are never used in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code. Notes:

You are never using the result of the clustering,you are comparing the original pixel values with `k`, instead of the clustered pixel values `idx`.

Also, remember to use `imshow(____, [])` if your images are not [0-1] or [0-255].

```
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYp7r.jpg');
im = rgb2gray(im);
[idx, centroids]=kmeans(double(im(:)),3,'distance','sqEuclidean','Replicates',3);

segmented_images = cell(1,3);
for k = 1:3
    color = zeros(size(im));
    color(idx==k) = im(idx==k);
    segmented_images{k} = color;
end

figure(),imshow(segmented_images{1},[]);
figure(),imshow(segmented_images{2},[]);
figure(),imshow(segmented_images{3},[]);
```